# Dynamic document.title using a $_SESSSION variable

Tags: php, ajax, title

I have a page that uses ajax to show users their current assignments.  Instead of having to refresh the page to see if there are any updates, I'm using ajax to update the data every 4 seconds.  It's been requested that I change the document title to show something like "Number of Tasks: 4" and have that update as well when the user either completes a new task, or gets assigned another one.  I tried using a simple "setInterval" javascript function, but since PHP is server side, the variable piece doesn't update...

I've also tried setting "document.title" from within the ajax code, but that just plain didn't work.

Is there a simple way to update the document title to show the number of tasks assigned to the user viewing the page?

Comment: well, when I tested it with window.document, it worked.... it just wouldn't update when a task was completed or a new one was assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return the value from the $_SESSION in the data sent with the AJAX response to the client Javascript code.  Once you have it on the client side set whatever you need to it with javascript.

Comment: @Brds you're ajax call can get a data set back.  On a successfull return it can execute a callback function using that that data.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to call with ajax a php dedicated to return you only the number of tasks (and other information you may want).

To change the title you can just call document.title = "the data returned in ajax";.

And put all this code (ajax call and title set) inside a function with setinterval as you mentioned.